# How can I make python pivot tables (margins = True) return the sum of the row/column, not the mean?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

When building a pivot table using pandas, I want to see the row and column totals in the final row/column. This should easily be done by setting margins to True, as according to the official pandas documentation:

```
**margins** *bool, default False*
Add all row / columns (e.g. for subtotal / grand totals).
```

Wherever I look, I see that this is what is supposed to happen. However, when I make a simple pivot table and set margins to True:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3],
    "B": ["X", "Z", "Z", "X", "X", "Z", "X", "X", "Z"],
    "C": [20, 22, 21, 21, 22, 21, 21, 20, 21]})

pt = df.pivot_table(values="A", columns = "B", index ="C", margins = True)

print(pt)
```

In the result, the "All" column just displays the *mean* values, not the sum. Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you for your time. This is my first ever post on this website as I only recently started coding. Not that it pertains to the question, I just thought I'd share this momentous occasion with you all.

Comment: there is an aggfunc parameter : ``df.pivot_table(values="A", columns = "B", index ="C", margins = True, aggfunc='sum')``

Comment: To clarify you want the margins to be the sum but you want to keep the aggregate values as means? Or you want to aggregate the cells as sums as well? Setting the aggfunc will do both. There will need to be another approach if you want mean aggregation and sum margins.

Comment: What is your expected output dataframe from these data?